# What are the most useful Xcode plugins?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, macos

What are the most useful plugins that you have found for Xcode?  I'm looking for ones that help to cut your development times.

I'm already using [ciaran's xcode-bracket-matcher](http://github.com/ciaran/xcode-bracket-matcher) myself, but I would be interested in any others that people have found to be helpful

Comment: Xcode already has the bracket-matching feature built-in; it's on the Text Editing pane. It sometimes guesses wrong, though; is the plug-in any better?

Answer (score 6):

I just came across [Code Pilot](http://codepilot.cc/). I don't know how long it's been around, but it deserves to be more well known. I came here looking for other unsung Xcode gems just like it, but it appears there aren't a lot out there. Also check out [Completion Dictionary](http://www.obdev.at/products/completion-dictionary/index.html) and [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html)

Comment: I come across this list of free Xcode plugins - [7 useful Xcode plugins](http://www.pashik.com/2013/02/12/5-useful-xcode-plugins/)

Comment: CodePilot has moved here: http://codepilot.cc/

Answer (score 2):

[Core Data code generation](http://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator)

Comment: I heard something about this plugin, many people loves it, have you use it before ?

Answer (score 2):

I am using [Code Pilot](http://macoscope.net/en/mac/codepilot/) for a couple of months, it is great tool, though have some little glitches.

I recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [Google Toolbox For Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/)'s Xcode plugin, which adds menu items to create a unit test executable and to manage code coverage analysis for a target.

Answer (score 1):

Clang analyser is one tool for finding bugs in the C and Obj-C code
http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/
Hope you are already using the performance tools like Instruments and Shark attached with XCode itself.

Comment: That's not a plug-in, though. It comes with Xcode.

Comment: I used to use clang static analyzer, It was very useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

To add code snippets I use [Completion Dictionary](http://www.obdev.at/products/completion-dictionary/index.html)